# How to use negative number as argument value in a drush command?

Tags: drush

I'm trying to create a drush command that need negative and positive numbers as argument, all works fine with the positive numbers, but once I tried to use the negative number I get this error:

```
[error]  Unknown option: --1.  See `drush help mw-reorder` for available options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0.
```

Is like there is no way to use a negative value because drush think that this is an option.

I looked inside the drush code but I didn't found anything.

Maybe the solution is use a special option in the command to says that the argument will be consider as a negative value or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Put it in quotes? The parser is looking for `-x` and `--xyz` to find options, if your `-` is in a quote it shouldn't be seen as one, and php doesnt mind getting a negative number as a string.

Comment: @Clive something like `drush mw-r devel '-1'` give me the same error.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, that way the last arg should be seen as a string arg instead of being parsed like an option

Comment: Oh didn't see that it gives the same error...that's a bit odd. Maybe try double quotes, they're usually interpreted differently

Comment: @Clive if you want to test the command install this module https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight/releases/8.x-1.x-dev

Comment: No need really, just `drush en "-1"` is enough to test whether it's accepting the arg or not (it's not)

Comment: Try `drush mw-r devel -- "-1"`, seems to work for me

Comment: @Clive same problem

Comment: Are you using an exotic shell perhaps? That should definitely work in bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash (and also works in fish)

Comment: @Clive I'm using the Terminal that comes with Mac, all works for me fine. this is the first problem that I found just today.

Comment: Not sure what to say, I'm on a Mac too and running `drush en  -1` in bash gives me "unknown option" while `drush en --  -1` tells me it can't find a module called "-1" (meaning the argument got through to drush correctly). It should work

Comment: Maybe it's the number of args, try `drush -- mw-r devel -1`

Comment: @Clive Same problem, try with the module to see if `drush mw-r devel -- "-1"` works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I added a new option named --minus for the drush command.

```
function modules_weight_drush_command() {
  $items['mw-reorder'] = [
    'description' => dt('Configures the module weight.'),
    'arguments' => [
      'module' => dt('The module machine name'),
      'weight' => dt('The module weight'),
    ],
    'options' => [
      'force' => [
        'description' => dt('If the option is present the core modules weight will be canged even if the option to allow it is disabled.'),
      ],
      'minus' => [
        'description' => dt('If the option is present the weight will be consider as a negative value. Read https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275 for more information.'),
      ],
    ],
    'aliases' => ['mw-r'],
    'examples' => [
      'mw-reorder node_revision_delete' => dt('Show the node_revision_delete module weight.'),
      'mw-reorder onlyone -5 --minus' => dt('Set the onlyone module weight to -5.'),
      'mw-reorder no_autocomplete 15' => dt("Set the no_autocomplete module weight to 15."),
      'mw-reorder views 10 --force' => dt("Force to set the views module weight to 15, even if the core module reorder option is disabled."),
    ],
  ];

 return $items;
}
```

And this is how will works:

```
function drush_modules_weight_mw_reorder() {
  // Getting the minus option.
  $minus = drush_get_option('minus');
  // Applying the minus option.
  $weight = $minus ? -1 * $args[1] : $args[1];
  // Setting the new weight. 
  module_set_weight($args[0], $weight);
  // Printing the message.
  $message = dt('The module weight for @module_name was updated to @weight.', ['@module_name' => $args[0], '@weight' => $weight]);
  drush_log($message, 'success');
}
```

If you want to see all the code take a look inside the issue [Allow to use negative values with the drush mw-reorder command](https://www.drupal.org/node/2910671#comment-12268133)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is not possible since the '-' is always picked up as an option being passed to the drush command.  I'd suggest evaluating why you need a negative value and if it could be handled with an absolute value and/or some other creative way of indicating a negative value.

If this is not an option, I found this work around in several different articles/blogs:

`php -r "print json_encode("-1");" | drush vset --format=json some_var_name - --y`

The drush command docs also suggest a technique using arrays for passing a complex data structure to the command: https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/variable-set/ (See the last example).  This would let you pass in almost anything you wanted.

Comment: I need a negative value because I'm setting the module weight, but at the end it seems that I will need to add an option in the command.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I think that this is a complicated way for a simple drush command

Comment: Thanks, but is a little weird to use this solution I think, the different between the positive and negative value will be enormous.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your module to accept a named parameter such as 'weight=5' or 'weight=-5' rather than a stand-alone numeric parameter.

It may work as a stand alone parameter entered as -'-5' or, if drush respects the common convention of '--' indicating end of flags, -- -5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 'weight=5' as parameter will work, but I think that will be a little strange for people that usually use drush to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have another less than ideal solution, I'm doing it as a drush sqlc command (I'm changing the variable table here):

`drush sqlq "update variable set value='s:3:\"-10\";' where name='uc_pane_delivery_weight'";`