# How to convert an url in a link?

Tags: 8, uri

I have some strings that can contain urls inside, and I need to convert this urls into links.

For example if a have this string:

```
Read for more information www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275
```

I need to obtain this string:

```
Read for more information <a href="http://www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275">www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't CKEditor do this?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, but the url is stored in a variable, take a look here: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/modules_weight/tree/modules_weight.drush.inc#n36

Comment: Sure you don't want it to be https instead of http these days?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens :-) I don't really remember how I get the url! :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this in **Drupal 8** we have in the Core the [filter_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!filter!src!Plugin!Filter!FilterUrl.php/class/FilterUrl/8.2.x) filter that convert URLs into links.

So we just need to apply the filter to our string.

```
use Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection;

// The text processing filters service.
$manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.filter');
// Getting filter plugin collection.
$filter_collection = new FilterPluginCollection($manager, []);
// Getting the filter_url plugin.
$filter = $filter_collection->get('filter_url');
// Setting the filter_url plugin configuration.
$filter->setConfiguration([
  'settings' => [
     'filter_url_length' => 496,
   ]
]);
// The string.
$input = 'Read for more information www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275';
// Applying the filter.
$result = _filter_url($input, $filter);

// To use dpm() you need the devel module.
dpm($result);
```

For **Drupal 7** is more simple

```
// Creating the filter.
$filter = new stdClass();
// Adding the filter settings.
$filter->settings = array(
  'filter_url_length' => 496,
);
// The string.
$input = 'Read for more information www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275';
// Applying the filter.
$result = _filter_url($input, $filter);

// To use dpm() you need the devel module.
dpm($result);
```

Output in both examples:

```
Read for more information <a href="http://www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275">www.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246298/28275</a>
```